# C++ If Statement Letter Reader

Tags: c++

I am trying to make it where you can say yes or Yes if you want a tutorial but it always runs 'cout' for the tutorial how do I fix the if statement to make it where I can type in yes or no and it will do depending on what I say, and please tell me why I have to do what I have to do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
string name;
cin >> name;
cout << name << " Will Now Be Your Business Name";
cout << " Would You Like A Tutorial? ";
string input;
cin >> input;
if (input != "Yes" || "yes"){
    cout << "You First Start With Naming Your Business Which Is What You Did And Then You \nCreate A Product By Entering In 'Create_Project' This Is How You Make Money ";
}
else if (input != "No" || "no"){
    int money = 1000;
    cout << "Money: " << money;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (input != "Yes" || "yes")` is **always** true. Did you mean `if (input != "Yes" || input != "yes")`? The same goes for `else if (input != "No" || "no")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (input != "Yes" || "yes")
```

You want

```
if (input != "Yes" || input != "yes")
```

Otherwise, "yes" is not compared to input, but evaluated as condition itself, and due to the workings of C++ is is true (ie. not false).
More detailed, anything not being 0 in some way is true. For the string "yes", the memory address is taken, and it's not 0.

Comment: Thank you, you explained it well to me, but it doesn't work I tried it and copied it from your text but it still didn't work and yes I changed it when they would answer no to "No" and "no" so is it my software or should I try a different technique like std::string::npos != input.find("no" || "No") or should I put std::string::npos != input.find after || too thanks.